# Accessing Meteor JS mobile app version

Tags: javascript, meteor, mobile

good day to all. I would like to ask for an advise on how to access mobile app version or info in Meteor JS. Is there a meteor or npm package or an API for this?

My aim is this, if I have a major update that requires user to update the app in Google play store or apple store, I want to display a modal saying "app requires an update" and the modal will not go away until the version is aligned (or the app is being updated).

**Problem**

I do not know how to get the app version info being installed by the user in their mobile devices so that I can compare it to the current version to check if they are aligned.

Any advise on how to handle this is meteor? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I got it all sorted out :) I found this very useful cordova plugin that allows me to get my mobile config version information

https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version

Everything is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has a thing called "hot code push" that obviates the need for updating the apk or app.

If you change the Cordova plugins, then you will need to re-issue the app, but if it's just code changes to the HTML/JS/CSS, the hot code push will do the job, and the user doesn't need to do anything.

There is a good discussion on the pros and cons of hot code push here: http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-hot-code-push

Comment: thanks you for the response, yes I am aware of the hot code push and my issue is on re-issuing the app because there are users does not know that there is already a new app update. I am planning to show a modal on the app if there is a new update when they open app, in other words they can not use the app until they update it.